# Getting the session Id from within a view component

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

This piece of code works fine to get the session Id from within the controller:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("_Name", "MyStore");
string SessionId = HttpContext.Session.Id;
```

... but when I try to put the same code in a view component class, VS tells me that the name `HttpContext.Session.SetString` (or just `HttpContext.Session`, or just `HttpContext`) does not exist in the current context. I have `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;` at the top of the class.

**edit**

Here is my view component class:

```
public class ShoppingCartViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly MyStoreContext _context;

    public ShoppingCartViewComponent(MyStoreContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // Initialize session to enable SessionId
    // THIS WON'T WORK:
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("_Name", "MyStore");
    string SessionId = HttpContext.Session.Id;

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int Id)
    {
        var cart = await GetCartAsync(Id);
        return View(cart);
    }

    private async Task<ViewModelShoppingCart> GetCartAsync(int Id)
    {
        var VMCart = await _context.ShoppingCarts
                    .Where(c => c.Id == Id)
                    .Select(cart => new ViewModelShoppingCart
                    {
                        Id = cart.Id,
                        Title = cart.Title,
                        CreateDate = cart.CreateDate,
                        ShoppingCartItems = cart.ShoppingCartItems
                                            .Select(items => new ViewModelShoppingCartItem
                                            {
                                                ProductId = items.ProductId,
                                                ProductTitle = items.Product.Title,
                                                ProductPrice = items.Product.Price,
                                                Quantity = items.Quantity
                                            }).ToList()
                    }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        return VMCart;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which bit is missing? Does `HttpContext` on it's own work? How about `HttpContext.Session`?

Comment: @DavidG None of the above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access a method that exists on an instance of `HttpContext`, not a static method. The easiest way is to let the depenancy injection framework give you a `IHttpContextAccessor`. For example:

```
public class ShoppingCartViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    private readonly MyStoreContext _context;

    public ShoppingCartViewComponent(MyStoreContext context,
        IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _context = context;
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;

        _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("_Name", "MyStore");
        string SessionId = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Id;
    }

    //snip rest of code for brevity    
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for being a total noob here, but I'm in the process of learning c# and asp.net. I don't understand how I'm supposed to implement your suggestion in my code. I have updated my question to include the whole view component class. Where and how should I set the SessionId-string's value?

Comment: I've udated the code to match yours as best I can. Where you actually do the set the session ID is up to you but this will show you how.

Comment: @DavidG great example and trying to use it now in 20, do you have to inject this anywhere so that you get the current session passed to the contextAccessor?